# Getting row which contain exact text

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a Table named Test. In which I have 3 columns.It looks like

imei is of type int, V_Id is of type int and **app_no is of type text**.

```
+-----------------+------------+------------+
|   imei_no       | V_Id      | app_no     | 
+-----------------+------------+------------+
|      7781112889 |       496 | 14,25      |
|     70433357641 |        498 | 125        |
|     70433357641 |        498 | 25         |
|     70433357641 |        498 | 254        |
|     70433357641 |        498 | 16,17,25   |
---------------------------------------------
```

i want to get rows which contains app_no=25.
I have used query containing LIKE and IN. 
Meaning **%25%**--- But it will also give me record where app_no=125 and app_no=254.
I have also tried "**like app_id='25'**" But it will exclude record where app_id=14,25.

Is there any other way by which I can get my desire record which contain all rows having app_id=25 including records like app_id=14,25. But excluding record where app_id=254,125.

Comment: Is there an ID column in your `test` table, which would be unique for every row?

Answer (score 4):

First, you should fix your data structure.  Storing lists of ids in a string is a bad idea for many reasons:

- Numbers should be stored as numbers, not strings.
- A column should have a single value.
- Ids should be declared using foreign key relationships.
- SQL (in general) does not have very good support for string functions.
- Queries on strings cannot use indexes, drastically reducing performance in some cases.

The SQL'ish way to store such data is in a separate table, with one row per `imei_no` and one per `app_no`.  This would be a junction table.

Sometimes, we are stuck with other people's really bad design decisions.  In that case, you can use `find_in_set()`:

```
on find_in_set(25, app_no)
```

Comment: Thank you very much for suggestion. I am heaving a situation where i have to store multiple app_id in one row. How can it be done?. And i am on a level where changing data structure is not possible cause, table is already linked with many usage. But i will keep in mind for future, for sure.

Comment: @RajTandel . . . I can't think of a reason why you would have to store ids on a single row.  Use a junction table.

Answer (score 1):

please use find in set

```
select * from <table_name> where FIND_IN_SET(app_no,'25')
```

Answer (score 1):

Use [`FIND_IN_SET`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/string-functions.html#function_find-in-set)

```
SELECT *
FROM test
WHERE FIND_IN_SET('25', app_no) > 0
```

I believe you can also do this using only the `LIKE` operator.  Assuming that your CSV list of app numbers have no spaces:

```
SELECT *
FROM test
WHERE app_no LIKE '25' OR
      app_no LIKE '25,%' OR
      app_no LIKE '%,25' OR
      app_no LIKE '%,25,%'
```

Comment: Fine solution. But in case of using LIKE it is excluding 14,25 and 25,16 cause it will precisely look for ',25' , '25,' and ',25,' so it will exclude.

Comment: @RajTandel Sorry updated my answer.  I can give you a solution for your CSV problem as well assuming you have a unique ID column.

Answer (score 0):

You can also use a simple REGIX like:

```
SELECT
  yourField,
  youtField REGEXP('^25$|^25,|,25$')
FROM youtTable;
```

**sample**

```
MariaDB [yourschema]> SELECT t,t REGEXP('^25$|^25,|,25$') FROM l;
+-------+----------------------------+
| t     | t REGEXP('^25$|^25,|,25$') |
+-------+----------------------------+
| 1     |                          0 |
| 2     |                          0 |
| 1,25  |                          1 |
| 1,125 |                          0 |
| 125,1 |                          0 |
| 25    |                          1 |
| 25,0  |                          1 |
+-------+----------------------------+
7 rows in set (0.00 sec)

MariaDB [yourschema]>
```